SSRS I'm having trouble setting the default Value of Date-Time Parameters using datasets
I have two parameters that I'm working with:
Parameter 1:
Name: endYear
Prompt: endYear
Data Type: Integer
Available Values: Specify Values (Label: 2023-24 Value: 2024; Label: 2024-25 Value: 2025)
Default Values: None
Parameter 2:
Name: fromDate
Prompt: From
Data Type: Date/Time
Available Values: None
Default Values: Get Values from a query (Dataset: Dates Value Field: fromDate)
Dataset:
Name: Dates
Data Source: A sql server
Parameters: The value from Parameter 1 (endYear)
Stored Procedure: rptCompoundDates
SQL:
@endYear int (the incoming parameter being passed in)
DECLARE @today SMALLDATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT  CAST(MIN(d.date) AS DATE) fromDate, 
        CAST(IIF(MAX(d.date) < @today, MAX(d.date), IIF(@today < MIN(d.date), MIN(d.date), @today)) AS DATE) toDate
FROM    jcps.dbo.Calendar cal
        JOIN jcps.dbo.school sch ON sch.schoolID = cal.schoolID 
          AND sch.stateClassification = 'A1'
        JOIN jcps.dbo.Day d ON d.calendarID = cal.calendarID 
          AND d.instruction = 1 
WHERE   cal.endYear = @endYear 

I have tested the output of the sql by passing in @endYear = 2024 and @endYear 2025 and the expected dates are being passed back out.
When I run the report, since I don't have a default end year selected, when I select either 2023-24 or 2024-25 the proper From date is returned and populates correctly Parameter 2 fromDate.
The problem is that when I select the other end year, it does not change the fromDate to be the correct value being passed in from the SQL, it remains whatever the original endYear value was.  Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?
enter image description here

this has always been a problem with cascading parameters.. once the first selection is made, subsequent parent parameter changes do not force the child to refresh.. apprently it is "by design"!!
Refer to this link : https://bpmsbi.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/ssrs-cascading-parameters-refresh-solved/

To add to Harry's comment, this is particularly problematic with date parameters and the DatePicker. Do you need the fromDate parameter to be editable? If not then just do the work in the main report dataset instead. If you do need it to be editable, set the Available Values to a list of valid dates based on the year and set the fromDate parameter to be text - not pretty but might be an option.
